# Show and hide button on scrolling ScrollView android

Tags: android, scroll, android-nestedscrollview

I have a `nested scrollview` and a `button`. I want to hide the button whenever the `scrollview` is scrolling and show the `button` when scrolling stops regardless of up scroll and down scroll. Someone please help.

Comment: are you using recyclerview inside nestedscrollview...?

Comment: yes. I am using

Comment: then try updated code https://stackoverflow.com/a/57672283/6834114

Answer (score 2):

Finally I have found the solution.

```
scrollView.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
            override fun onTouch(p0: View?, p1: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
                when (p1!!.getAction()) {
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL, MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                        closeCaseButton.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    }
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                        closeCaseButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                }
                return false
            }
        })
```

Comment: Your answer is right but it will not provide proper effect like hiding and showing fab when scroll view is scrolling

Answer (score 0):

You can use this listener

```
mScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(
new OnScrollChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {
        int scrollY = rootScrollView.getScrollY(); // If you are dealing with ScrollView
        int scrollX = rootScrollView.getScrollX(); // If you are dealing with HorizontalScrollView
        // DO SOMETHING 
        // E.g : myBtn.setVisibility( View.GONE );
    }
    });
```

Comment: I wanted to hide the button when scroll starts and show the button when scrolling stops.

Answer (score 0):

try to use NestedScrollview listner like below

```
 nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            if(scrollY>oldScrollY){
              //your visibility code here
            }
        }
    });
```

here

> scrollX = new horizontal scroll position
>
> oldScrollX = previous horizontal scroll position
>
> scrollY = new vertical scroll position
>
> oldScrollY = previous vertical scroll position

**UPDATE**

If you are using recycler and want to monitor scroll state then try below this may help

```
 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int scrollState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, scrollState);
                switch(scrollState) {
                    case 2: // SCROLL_STATE_FLING 
                        //hide button here
                        break;

                    case 1: // SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL 
                        //hide button here
                        break;

                    case 0: // SCROLL_STATE_IDLE 
                        //show button here
                        break;

                    default:
                        //show button here
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I wanted to hide the button when scroll starts and show the button when scrolling stops.

Answer (score 0):

check in this way

```
        nested_scroll.setOnScrollChangeListener(object : NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        fun onScrollChange(v: NestedScrollView, scrollX: Int, scrollY: Int, oldScrollX: Int, oldScrollY: Int) {

            if (scrollY > oldScrollY) {
                Log.e("#####", "Scroll Down")
            } else if (scrollY < oldScrollY) {
                Log.e("#####", "Scroll Up")
            } else if (scrollY == 0) {
                Log.e("#####", "Top Scroll")
            } else if (scrollY == v.getMeasuredHeight() - v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight()) {
                Log.e("#####", "Bottom Scroll")
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: I wanted to hide the button when scroll starts and show the button when scrolling stops.

Comment: in those conditions pls Use button.setVisibility(GONE); or button.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your request – hide the button when scrolling and show it when the scroll stop.

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.idOfRecyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));

    // To hide the add button on scroll
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {    
        if (dy > 0 || dy < 0 && addExpenseButton.isShown()) {
                button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }
    });
```

Here a part of the layout:

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/headerLayout">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/idOfRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:listSelector="@color/transparent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This link is useful
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-detect-end-of-scrollview-in-android

and for the animated hide and show you can use .hide() and .show() methods with FloatingActionButton reference